# Substring in insert command

Tags: c#

I have a field that is 50 caracters long so I need to do a sub-string but in insert command, but first I have to check if the value is to long and then sub-string this is the part of the code, I know it's not good, so how can this be done?

```
myQuery = "INSERT INTO ERP_HEADER(IDOC_NUM,SEG_NUM,DOCTYP,HDRNUM,WHNUM,DOCNUM,DOCNOT)" +
                                  "VALUES(" + Lidoc_num + ",'" +
                                              SEG_NUM + "','" +
                                              drDOK["DOCTYP"] + "'," +
                                              drDOK["HDRNUM"] + "," +
                                              drDOK["WHNUM"] + "," +
                                              drDOK["DOCNUM"] + ",'" +
                                              drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString().Replace("'", string.Empty).Length > 50 ? Substring(0,50) + "')";
```

Comment: First thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, for various reasons, including eliminating SQL injection attacks - then you don't need to remove the `'` anyway. Next, use a local variable rather than trying to do everything in a single expression.

Comment: Well I know that...but the problem is that I'm doing a fix of a production code that someone else wrote so I can't do much about it... :-(

Comment: I don't see why "I'm fixing production code" means that you can't fix potentially serious security bugs... and I *certainly* don't see why it means you can't use a local variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you should read carefully and adapt your code based on Jon Skeet's comment.

Beside that, you could write a small extension method

```
public static string ToShortenString(this string str, int maxLength) {
   if (str == null) return null;//or string.Empty if you want to "hide" null values
   return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength));
}
```

then you could change your code to

```
drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString().Replace("'", string.Empty).ToShortenString(50) + "')";
```

Comment: @CrBruno of course, this method should be in a static helper class.

Comment: I need some help...I made this static class Helper
    {
        public static string ToShortenString(this string str, int maxLength)
        {
            if (str == null) return null;  //or string.Empty if you want to "hide" null values
            return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength));
        }
    } But now I need to call that class...how to do this?

Comment: @CrBruno just reference the namespace of the new class `using <thenamespace wherey you can find the Helper class>;` (if that's not in the same namespace) and use it like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
myQuery = "INSERT INTO ERP_HEADER(IDOC_NUM,SEG_NUM,DOCTYP,HDRNUM,WHNUM,DOCNUM,DOCNOT)" +
                                  "VALUES(" + Lidoc_num + ",'" +
                                              SEG_NUM + "','" +
                                              drDOK["DOCTYP"] + "'," +
                                              drDOK["HDRNUM"] + "," +
                                              drDOK["WHNUM"] + "," +
                                              drDOK["DOCNUM"] + ",'" +
                                              drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString().Replace("'", string.Empty).Length > 50 ? drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString().Substring(0,50) : drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks,but is there a way to do this inside insert command, because I another insert I have 50 values, so that means 50 variables

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ERP_HEADER(@IDOC_NUM,@SEG_NUM,@DOCTYP,@HDRNUM,@WHNUM,@DOCNUM,@DOCNOT)", connection);

string DOCNOT = drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString()
if(DOCNOT.Length > 50)
    DOCNOT = DOCNOT.Substring(0,50);    

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDOC_NUM", Lidoc_num);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEG_NUM", SEG_NUM);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCTYP", drDOK["DOCTYP"]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HDRNUM", drDOK["HDRNUM"]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHNUM", drDOK["WHNUM"]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCNUM", drDOK["DOCNUM"]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCNOT", DOCNOT);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Never ever concatenate sql-strings, it's just like asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters to avoid SQL injection like Jon skeet already pointed out and avoid syntactic abomniations:

```
//assuming myQuery is of type SqlCommand
myQuery = "INSERT INTO ERP_HEADER(IDOC_NUM,SEG_NUM,DOCTYP,HDRNUM,WHNUM,DOCNUM,DOCNOT)" +
          "VALUES( @Lidoc_num, @SEG_NUM, @DOCTYPHDRNUM, @WHNUM, @DOCNUM, @DOCNOT)";

myquery.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("Lidoc_num", Lidoc_num);
//...other values
myQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOCNUM", drDOK["DOCNUM"]);
string DOCNOT = drDOK["DOCNOT"].ToString();
//check for your string
if(DOCNOT.Length > 50)
    DOCNOT = DOCNOT.Substring(0,50);
myQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOCNOT", DOCNOT);
```